svg images not showing on the github pages
The problem is that the GitHub pages not showing the images it says 404 not found in the console you can check my repo and git page please help
**here is the error : **
newsletter-sign-up-w…success-message/:29
GET https://codeshinobi-sarthak.github.io/assets/images/illustration-sign-up-mobile.svg 404 (Not Found)
newsletter-sign-up-w…uccess-message/:107
GET https://codeshinobi-sarthak.github.io/assets/images/illustration-sign-up-desktop.svg 404 (Not Found)
style.css:1
GET https://codeshinobi-sarthak.github.io/assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GitHub repo: https://github.com/codeShinobi-sarthak/newsletter-sign-up-with-success-message
GitHub pages : https://codeshinobi-sarthak.github.io/newsletter-sign-up/
"Thank you for your help."
i have tried to redeploy using git pages also remake the repo but still it persists and also change the paths

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please read Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

You can change the repo name: codeshinobi-sarthak.github.io to make this work
Or change the src of the img to https://codeshinobi-sarthak.github.io/newsletter-sign-up-with-success-message/assets/images/illustration-sign-up-mobile.svg.
If the repo name matches your GitHub username, the site will be hosted at username.github.io/. Otherwise, it will be hosted at username.github.io/repo-name/.
Thus, the svg is on https://codeshinobi-sarthak.github.io/newsletter-sign-up-with-success-message/assets/images/illustration-sign-up-mobile.svg.
You can see my website for it: https://github.com/Sivayogeith/sivayogeith.github.io and https://sivayogeith.github.io
Also, at Ulagellam, the company I work at: https://github.com/Ulagellam/ulagellam.com and https://ulagellam.com.

       well i change the url and no error is there i the console but the image is still not displaying

@sarthakSanskari No, you have to change it to: https://codeshinobi-sarthak.github.io/newsletter-sign-up/assets/images/illustration-sign-up-mobile.svg. The github pages url not at github.com
